# HTML form action to python > how to save a local file from browser that was generated by python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, forms

I have a form that when submitted runs through a python script for processing.  When I hit the submit button it opens a download window asking to save pyscript.py instead of displaying the contents of my final print statement.

### HTMl:

```
<html>
<form action="/cgi-bin/pyscript.py" method="get" class="darkform">
  <div id="button">
    < input type="submit" value="Generate" class="button">
  </div>
</form>
</html>
```

### python

```
f = open(confdir + _hostname_ + "_config.txt" ,'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()

print newdata
```

---

The script creates a local .txt file and I would like to have the submit button generate the file and either display it in the browser directly or prompt to download the .txt file.  Again, currently when you hit submit it starts a download of pyscript.py.  If I change the file extension of the downloaded file to .txt it opens perfectly.  I should mention that this is my first python script I ever wrote, so I'm sure a simple print at the end isn't the best way to achieve my goal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have searched all over the forums and can't find anything related.

Comment: What web server are you using to run your CGI script(s)?

Comment: I am running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not given any specifics of the "Web Server" you are using I can only give a very general response:

1. Your "Web Server" is not properly configured for CGI esp. with regards to Python (`*.py`) as CGI. See: [Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) for Apache.
2. Your response (*if you want your Browser/User-Agent to be able to download it and treat it as a downloadable file*) must respond with the following HTTP Header(s)

*Headers:*

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<file name.ext>"
```